# Maven failing to build multi-module project only on a specific machine (works everywhere else)

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, pom.xml

I have a multi-module maven project that I inherited from another team and am now migrating to a cloud solution. We were able to get it working in a co-worker machine and pushed it to git. However, after I pull the exact same version of the code, it fails to compile on my machine with the obvious

> cannot find symbol

The missing class is packaged in a dependency jar that is not declared in the pom, so it can only be a transitive dependency. However, I can't generate an effective pom to check this (because of the compilation issues, I suppose).

This is only failing for me, not my co-worker, so it really can't be a problem with the dependency declaration in the pom file. I'm running maven 3.5.0, from the main project folder, with exactly the same vm args and profile as my co-worker, except that it works for him and not for me.

The only difference between the two machines is I'm in mac and he's in good old Linux.

Does anyone has any idea what is messing my local build or what I should try to look for next?

I know it's a very vague question, but I'm completely at a loss. Fully available to send any more information required to help me out with this. Maybe I'm simply doing smt really stupid I can't put my finger on. Or maybe not. Any ideas?

Comment: It might be worth trying to delete your ~/.m2 directory (or at least the jars included that might be causing problems), and seeing if that resolves anything.

Comment: `mvn dependency:tree` works without compiling

Comment: Pull the dependency jar from both your buddies and your local ~/.m2 directory and compare them. If they are different then that may be why it works on his box but not yours.

Comment: Need to compare the `~/.m2/settings.xml` files. One may be hitting a different remote repo, have different mirror settings, etc. than the other.

Comment: I already deleted all the dependencies in the m2 directory, including the settings.xml, but settings.xml was the same anyway. Will try the dependency:tree and compare with my co-worker. I'd expect it to be the same, but at this point, I'll try anything!!!

Comment: Can you copy-paste the entire related log, not only the error message? Also you mentionned the "missing class is packaged in a dependency jar that is not declared in the pom", are you sure said class is available on your build path? If you can share your pom.xml that may also help ;)

Comment: Is this other dependency jar provided via a repository manager ? Furthermore why is this not declared in the pom file as dependency if it is needed? That sounds weird...

Comment: So it seems this class was actually in the code, but with a package with the same name as the dependency I mentioned (that was not added to the pom file). The reason why this didn't work is because there is a hidden .gitignore file adding this file, for some reason, so the file was not getting to git and I was not pulling it, of course. Doesn't seem to be generated, so I don't see any reason for it to be ignored. Anyway, it's working now... thanks for the help!

Comment: Considering this is not really an actual error, should I delete the post? There's no point in me putting an answer to my own question, is there? How often will someone hide a .gitignore to ignore a vital file in the code? What's the "normal" way to handle these situations?